# The cakephp query in array does not work

Tags: cakephp

**cakephp support**

> $this->Order->find('all',
>   array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>array(1,2,3,4))));

but, when I pass on the variable :

> $arr = array(     (int) 0 => '1',     (int) 1 => '128',   (int) 2 => '120',
>     (int) 3 => '9',     (int) 4 => '122' );
>
> $this->Order->find('all',
>   array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$arr)));

=> it does not work.
because only the array format $arr = array(1,2,3,4,...) => it work.

I use

> implode(',', $arr) => $arr = '1,128,120,9,122'

=> it does not work.
how to convert

> $arr = array(     (int) 0 => '1',     (int) 1 => '128',   (int) 2 => '120',
>     (int) 3 => '9',     (int) 4 => '122' ); => array(1,128,120,9,122) ?

Comment: Can you show clear error if you have any ?

Comment: no errors. only conditions 'user_id' => $arr . with the array $arr = array( (int) 0 => '1', (int) 1 => '128', (int) 2 => '120', (int) 3 => '9', (int) 4 => '122' );then it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

```
$arr = array(
    (int) 0 => '1',
    (int) 1 => '128',
    (int) 2 => '120',
    (int) 3 => '9',
    (int) 4 => '122'
);

$this->Order->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'User.id' => array_values($arr)
    )
));
```

Comment: $this->Order->find('all', array(
    'conditions'=>array(
        'User.id' => array_values($arr)
    )
)); as well as on it does not work.I am also use this case and it was not running conditions

Comment: What's the name of the field that holds the User.id value in Order Model?

Answer (score 0):

Use only `array_values($array);` see [array_values](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-values.php)